# Comparing Meta Field date in WPQuery using Meta_Query?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query, date

I have dates stored in the format d-m-Y, and i want to display any posts that are in the past, before today.

```
    $args = array (
        'post_type'=>'property',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'posts_per_page'=> 8,
        'paged'=> $paged,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'auction_date',
            'value' => date( 'd-m-Y'),
            'compare' => '<',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
      );
```

This doesn't seem to work and i can't figure out why.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACF stores it's dates in Ymd format, this is why i couldn't compare.

Make sure your date is in Ymd format when you compare it against an ACF datefield.